# Use Python to Access Battery Status in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to come out with a small python script to monitor the battery state of my ubuntu laptop and sound alerts if it's not charging as well as do other stuff (such as suspend etc).
I really don't know where to start, and would like to know if there is any library for python i can use.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you can find the information you are looking for in

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0
```

Comment: any ideas how i could find out if my battery is charging or not (and it's current level) from python?

Comment: never mind, figured it out, turns out there are readable files in this directory which are updated with various details about the battery.
eg. cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/present outputs 1 signifying that battery is present.
Thanks

Comment: I think you can also query battery status via dbus from gnome-power-manager.

Answer (score 2):

Here I found a solution that might be helpful for you too.
http://mantoshkumar1.blogspot.in/2012/11/monitoring-battery-status-on-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

The the "power" library on pypi is a good bet, it's cross platform too.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use any module for this.

Simply you can navigate to

*/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0*.

Here you will find a lot of files with information about your battery. 
You will get current charge in charge_now file and total charge in charge_full file. 
Then you can calculate battery percentage by using some math.

Note:- You may need root access for this. You can use *sudo nautilus* command to open directories in root mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small piece of code that I wrote.  Fredrik Pihl's reply helped me.

```
import time
from playsound import playsound

# contains battery remaining power
statusf = "/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity"
# keep checking the power
with open(statusf) as f:
    while True:
        pow_= f.read()
        print(pow_)
        if float(pow_) < 15.0:
            print("power crisis!!")
            while True:
                # beeps until killed
                playsound('beep.wav')
                time.sleep(2)
        time.sleep(5 * 60)
```